# How to send an email on MacOS when completing a render?

Tags: python, scripting

So this is the email setup:

```
    import ssl
    import smtplib

    port = 465  # For SSL
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    sender_email = "From@example.com"
    receiver_email = "To@example.com"
    password = "password"

    message = f"""\
    Subject: Email Sent from Blender on MacOS
    
    This Email was sent from Python in Blender on MacOS.
    """

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Pretty easy, nothing special. When running this in Python 3.10 on my machine I receive the email and all is good.

But then this error message appears when I run this code as a script in Blenders IDE:

```
location: <unknown location>:-1
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.1/python/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 1050, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.1/python/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.1/python/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.1/python/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 1057, in _get_socket
    new_socket = self.context.wrap_socket(new_socket,
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.1/python/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.1/python/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.1/python/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)
```

So why is this happening? Well as far as I can tell this is the solution:
On your Mac go to `Macintosh HD > Applications > Python3.##` then run the file `Install Certificates.command`. And this fixed the issue for me when running a normal Python interpreter using say Pycharm.

As far as I can tell `Install Certificates.command` is no where to be found inside the Blender internal Python version. My question is, how do I generate valid SSL certificates inside Blenders Python version without the `Install Certificates.command` file?

All I want to do is send emails from Blender. Thank you for reading and for your time!

Comment: can you try this? https://exerror.com/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/

Comment: Could your problem be solved? I would be grateful for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As @HarryMcKenzie correctly mentioned in the comment, the library to verify the SSL certificate seems to be missing.

However, as far as I know, you would have to install additional Python libraries in this way so that you can use them directly in Blender:

```bash
# Navigate to the installation directory
cd /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.1/python/bin/
# Use blender's bundled python & install/upgrade the package
python -m ensurepip
python -m pip install --upgrade certifi
```